# android export signed vs unsigned application

Tags: android, apk

I have multiple developers working on a project. When they just run the program and then manually get the APK, our testers have to uninstall and re-install for each different developer that publishes the APK (something about debugging key). So I am wondering, what if I make them all use `android tools> export unsigned application package`? will that solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should create a new debug keystore for your team and check it in to our project repository. Then have each of them open **Eclipse > Preferences > Android > Build** and change the "default debug keystore" value to point to this new keystore. That way they all use the same debug keystore and you dont have to worry about signing debug builds yourself.

Answer (score 1):

By default eclipse signs it with the default key which is different for different systems and on any android device if you try to reinstall it without first uninstalling it treats it as an update and it requires the update to be signed with the same key with which installed application is signed so follow what Karakuri suggested and it should solve your problem.